# `database_configuration' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Briefing: I've been attempting to deploy my blog to heroku for the last week with no luck. I've contacted Heroku support and they've pretty much told me to post the log on stackoverflow. So here I am.

Look's like there is some sort of database configuration error, but I'm having toruble pin-pointing it. Anyway here's the codebase: www.github.com/apane/blogit_blog.

Heroku log below.

Gemfile provided for good measure:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'blogit', '0.8.0'

gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"

gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"

end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'  
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
Rake db:migrate error log:
```

Heroku log:

```
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 8 column 16
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

### New error:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/personal_blog/personal_blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: those aren't heroku logs - they're referencing your local machine. Show the logs of what happens when you deploy it, if that's where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out your `database.yml` file, because currently you have it set for sqlite, while in your gemfile you've determine postgresql to be your database. There is also the fact that your production section has an extra indentation.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_dev
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: u

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: u

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: u
```

Note that you should also create a `blog_dev` and `blog_test` database. I would also replace

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"
end
```

with this

```
gem 'pg'
gem "unicorn", "~> 4.6.2"
```

in your `gemfile`.

It also looks like either you haven't created your database or you haven't turned on Postgresql. Not sure you're set up for postgresql, but if you have a Mac OS X I find the [Postgres](http://postgresapp.com/) app to be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, in your database.yml file there is an indentation mismatch in line 22, the word `production` should be in parallel with other titles `development`, `test`.

This is because YAML files are space sensitive; [read more about YAML here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

Comment: Thanks Sameera, I've followed your instructions and it helped with the initial error. However, there is now a postgreSQL connection error. I've updated the initial post with the new error. Please see above.